# Reusable Color Extension Crashing in SwiftUI Preview

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to be able provide color extensions for reuse throughout components I am working on. Unfortunately - when I try to view the effect of these extensions in the preview editor - it reliably crashes. That said - when the project is built and run - the colors display correctly without issue. Is there a way for the approach illustrated below to work in the Xcode preview editor?

Example extension:

```
extension Color {
  static let themeBlue = Color(red: 0.0, green: 0.322, blue: 1.0, opacity: 0.677)
}
```

Example Usage

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .foregroundColor(.themeBlue)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Is there an additional context that needs to be provided to the `PreviewProvider`? Or perhaps additional settings in Xcode need to be configured for this work in the previewer? Or is this actually a known issue?

This is using Xcode Version 11.3 (11C29) and Swift 5

Comment: I will note that slapping this code into a new project works fine for me. The preview doesn't crash. So I would try deleting derived data.

Comment: Agreed. No issues with Xcode 11.3, iOS 13.3 here in canvas preview or on device.

Comment: @CalebKleveter thanks for the sanity check on this - deleting derived data indeed solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably just a caching issue that can be resolved by deleting your derived data.